# what is the best practise for mixins in Vuejs?

Tags: vue.js, vue-directives

I'm learning Vuejs and I wonder what's the best practise for mixins in Vuejs. And how can mixin object contain other component options.

Comment: Documentation answers this question very clearly.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Mixins are simply a way in to avoid repetition of code and share the same code in various components. For eg. you might have a method that prints something to the console in a number of components Now, rather than writing it in all the components every time you just create a mixin and import it in all the components where it is needed.

Let me know if this clarifies.

You can read more about it here (https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/mixins.html)